# How to delete dev profile in Intellij? and Why Maven profiles in Intellij has three states?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, maven-profiles

## Question 1:

Erveytime I import a maven project from existing source, Intellij create a dev profile, but there is no such a dev profile in pom.xml. Here is my profiles in pom.xml:

[image]

But, there is a dev profile shown in maven projects window:

[image]

How to delete the inexplicable dev profile?

## Question 2:

All the checkbox I have seen before have two states: checked or unchecked. However, the checkbox of a profile in Intellij has three states:

[image]

[image]

[image]

What's the difference?

Comment: have you checked your settings.xml (normally in ~/.m2) if these profiles are defined there?

Comment: @P.J.Meisch Thank you, genius. There is a dev profile in settings.xml. Could you help to answer the second question?

Answer (score 1):

To answer Your first question (from my comment):

the *dev* profile is defined in your settings.xml .

The second question:

If the checkbox is on, then when you run a maven task from within IntelliJ, the profile is explicitly added to the mvn call with `-P dev`.

If you switch it off (no checkmark), it is explicitly excluded in the mvn call: `-P !dev`.

And in the third state (grey checkmark) no special profile argument is passed and so wether the profile is active is decided how you defined it in your config.

Comment: We have no evidence that your answer to the first question is right, though it may be, and I think your answer to the second question is just wrong. The grey tick is for automatically activated profiles, and the white tick is for manually activating profiles in the IDE so that they affect the project immediately (this may import new dependencies, plugins, repositories, etc.)

Comment: @EngineerDollery: the first answer was confirmed by the OP in a comment,  and the effect of the checkbox (and the passing of the -P arguments) can be seen in the output of the mvn commands in the run window

Comment: @EngineerDollery, the answer of first question is right, there is really a dev profile in my ~/.m2/settings.xml

Comment: I didn't say that the first one was wrong, only that the question doesn't give the settings.xml so it hadn't been confirmed. The second one is well wrong, despite your comments regarding -p, that's not what's happening (though I can see why you think it would be). The white tick enables a profile for intellij -- e.g. if you want intellij to 'see' a dependency defined in a profile (and offer code completion), or to be able to use a plug-in defined in a profile, then you must manually activate it (white tick). This will have a greater effect than using -P, which only enables the profile for mvn